# How to check relationship exist for Eloequent polymorphic?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hi how can I check for Eloquent polymorphic relationship already exist?

For example, I want to prevent data with same upload_id, attachable_id and attachable_type from getting store in the attachments table (refer to the highlight)

What I have try but did not get correct count of relationship exist:

```
//get count of attachment
$application->has('attachments')->count()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just query the related attachments for that `upload_id`:

```
$hasAttachments = $application->attachments()
    ->where('upload_id', $upload_id)
    ->count() > 0;
```

Comment: thanks it work why I cant think of using this basic checking :(